# If specific CSS class-combination is present, change CSS of another class

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I also want to change the background-color of "three" to "lightblue", but only if the class-combination "one current" exists on the page. Note: "three" can't get an additional class. I know, you can do this with JavaScript, but is there also a native CSS solution?

Here's my example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style> 
    .one.current {background-color: lightblue;}
  </style>
</head>
<body>
 <header>
  <p class="one current">The first paragraph.</p>
 </header>

 <main>
  <p class="two">The second paragraph.</p>
  <p class="three">The third paragraph.</p>
  <p class="four">The fourth paragraph.</p>
 </main>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you apply `one current` to a predecessor of them? In this case, `<body>`?

Comment: Or, at least, to the `header` element, so `.one.current + main > .three` would work

Comment: @IlyaStreltsyn Can you give me your code snippet? Doesn't seem to work for me...

Comment: I posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

In your case you could use `.one.current` in the `<header>`

Then style `.three` with:
`.one.current ~ main .three`

And the `<p>` element inside the header with:
`.one.current p`

> Documentation about the `~` operator:  [general sibling selector (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors).

Comment: Yes, that's it. Do you also have a solution, if "one current" is within "header", and the rest is within "main"?

Comment: Why do you think that `.one.current ~ .three` would work? `one.current` is wrapped in a `<header>` that is itself a sibling of the `.three` element; without a parent-selector this is (currently) impossible with css.

Comment: In my initial question, "header" and "main" were missing, so Razär's answer was correct. Sorry for the confusion. But yeah, without a parent-selector you can't solve it...

Comment: @bodemiller1, it will only work if both elements selected are siblings. So `<header>` must have the classes, then you can style `<p>` by using `.one.current p`

Answer (score 0):

If you can set class for `header` element instead of `p` element inside it, you can address the paragraph inside the sibling element using the following combination of selectors:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style> 
    .one.current p {background-color: lightblue;}
    .one.current + main > .three {background-color: lightblue;}
  </style>
</head>
<body>
 <header class="one current">
  <p>The first paragraph.</p>
 </header>

 <main>
  <p class="two">The second paragraph.</p>
  <p class="three">The third paragraph.</p>
  <p class="four">The fourth paragraph.</p>
 </main>
</body>
</html>
```